# Why do I need any Saga storage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nhibernate, nservicebus

I'm struggling with an error message I'm getting from the NServiceBus.Host during startup and not sure where I'm going wrong. I initially encountered the problem within a large project but I seem to be able to reproduce this from scratch.

In VS2012, start with a new C# Class Library project, set for .NET 4.6.2. Then add NuGet packages - NServiceBus (6.0.0), NServiceBus.Host (7.0.1) and NServiceBus.NHibernate (7.2.0).

Then edit the `EndpointConfiguration` class to be as follows:

```
using NServiceBus.Features;
using NServiceBus.Persistence;

namespace NSB6_Pure
{
  using NServiceBus;

  public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint
  {
    public void Customize(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
      //TODO: NServiceBus provides multiple durable storage options, including SQL Server, RavenDB, and Azure Storage Persistence.
      // Refer to the documentation for more details on specific options.
      endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Timeouts>();
      endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<MessageDrivenSubscriptions>();
      endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<Sagas>();
      // NServiceBus will move messages that fail repeatedly to a separate "error" queue. We recommend
      // that you start with a shared error queue for all your endpoints for easy integration with ServiceControl.
      endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");

      // NServiceBus will store a copy of each successfully process message in a separate "audit" queue. We recommend
      // that you start with a shared audit queue for all your endpoints for easy integration with ServiceControl.
      endpointConfiguration.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit");
    }
  }
}
```

Then compile (in this case a debug build) and, from a command prompt, try to run `NServiceBus.Host.exe` in the `bin\Debug` directory. In my case, I get this output, most of it in Red:

```
2017-04-28 12:46:11.876 INFO  DefaultFactory Logging to 'C:\blah\bin\Debug\' with level Info
2017-04-28 12:46:13.446 FATAL NServiceBus.LicenseManager Your license has expire
d! You can renew it at https://particular.net/licensing.
2017-04-28 12:46:13.561 ERROR NServiceBus.GenericHost Exception when starting en
dpoint.
System.InvalidOperationException: In order to use NServiceBus with NHibernate yo
u need to provide at least one connection string. You can do it via (in order of
 precedence):
 * specifying 'NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/Saga' connection string for th
e Saga persister
 * specifying 'NServiceBus/Persistence' connection string that applies to all pe
rsisters
 * specifying 'NServiceBus/Persistence/connection.connection_string' or 'NServic
eBus/Persistence/connection.connection_string_name' value in AppSettings or your
 NHibernate configuration file.
For most scenarios the 'NServiceBus/Persistence' connection string is the best o
ption.
   at NServiceBus.Persistence.NHibernate.NHibernateConfigurationBuilder.Validate
ConfigurationViaConfigFile(Configuration configuration, String configPrefix) in
C:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate\Internal\NHiberna
teConfigurationBuilder.cs:line 130
   at NServiceBus.Features.NHibernateStorageSession.Setup(FeatureConfigurationCo
ntext context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate
\SynchronizedStorage\NHibernateStorageSession.cs:line 45
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(FeatureInfo featureI
nfo, List`1 featuresToActivate, IConfigureComponents container, PipelineSettings
 pipelineSettings) in C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Features\FeatureActivator.cs
:line 194
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.SetupFeatures(IConfigureComponents c
ontainer, PipelineSettings pipelineSettings) in C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Fe
atures\FeatureActivator.cs:line 57
   at NServiceBus.InitializableEndpoint.<Initialize>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Build\
src\NServiceBus.Core\InitializableEndpoint.cs:line 50
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.<Start>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\fc89e
968acb99302\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line 48
2017-04-28 12:46:13.582 ERROR NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost Start fail
ure
System.InvalidOperationException: In order to use NServiceBus with NHibernate yo
u need to provide at least one connection string. You can do it via (in order of
 precedence):
 * specifying 'NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/Saga' connection string for th
e Saga persister
 * specifying 'NServiceBus/Persistence' connection string that applies to all pe
rsisters
 * specifying 'NServiceBus/Persistence/connection.connection_string' or 'NServic
eBus/Persistence/connection.connection_string_name' value in AppSettings or your
 NHibernate configuration file.
For most scenarios the 'NServiceBus/Persistence' connection string is the best o
ption.
   at NServiceBus.Persistence.NHibernate.NHibernateConfigurationBuilder.Validate
ConfigurationViaConfigFile(Configuration configuration, String configPrefix) in
C:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate\Internal\NHiberna
teConfigurationBuilder.cs:line 130
   at NServiceBus.Features.NHibernateStorageSession.Setup(FeatureConfigurationCo
ntext context) in C:\BuildAgent\work\5135de308b2f3016\src\NServiceBus.NHibernate
\SynchronizedStorage\NHibernateStorageSession.cs:line 45
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(FeatureInfo featureI
nfo, List`1 featuresToActivate, IConfigureComponents container, PipelineSettings
 pipelineSettings) in C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Features\FeatureActivator.cs
:line 194
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.SetupFeatures(IConfigureComponents c
ontainer, PipelineSettings pipelineSettings) in C:\Build\src\NServiceBus.Core\Fe
atures\FeatureActivator.cs:line 57
   at NServiceBus.InitializableEndpoint.<Initialize>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Build\
src\NServiceBus.Core\InitializableEndpoint.cs:line 50
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.<Start>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\fc89e
968acb99302\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line 54
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
ification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost.Start() in C:\BuildAgent\work\fc89
e968acb99302\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\WindowsHost.cs:line 33
```

And the bit I'm focussing on is here:

> In order to use NServiceBus with NHibernate you need to provide at least one connection string. You can do it via (in order of precedence):
>
> - specifying 'NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/Saga' connection string for the Saga persister

I've checked the NServiceBus code - this isn't a *generic* message. If the issue was the lack of config for Timeouts<sup>1</sup>, I'm sure it would be talking about it rather than Saga, since that part of the error message is parameterized.

But I don't want to use Sagas in this particular project. I'd have thought `DisableFeature<Sagas>` would be sufficient to indicate to NServiceBus that I don't want to use sagas here, but apparently not.

So why is NServiceBus trying to configure Saga storage and, more importantly, how do I stop it from doing so?

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, I am *expecting* such an error to occur since I haven't done anything such as even adding an `app.config` to the class library yet. So even once the Saga issue is resolved, I'm expecting this code to still produce errors. Just hopefully ones I can work out how to fix for myself.

(The rationale behind my wanting to avoid configuring any storage is that the real work to do is to upgrade some existing endpoints that have dedicated databases for each feature (Timeouts/Subscriptions/Sagas) and although I've been recommending for a while that we ought to merge these databases, and could thus just configure a `NServiceBus/Persistence` database for each endpoint, that's not been approved. But I'm loath to add *another* database for some of these endpoints when they only use timeouts at present)

Comment: But doesn't timeout storage needs connection string anyway?

Comment: @Evk - even if timeout storage configuration is added, the sample still complains about the lack of Saga storage. Since it complains anyway, I decided not to complicate the example by also needing to have a specific config file.

Comment: Try to do `endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<NHibernateStorageSession>();`, this should get you through this error, but I'm not really sure it's suitable in your situation (that you can do what you want with this feature disabled).

Comment: And even if you cannot disable that feature (NHibernateStorageSessio‌​n) you should at least know that this feature is what causing this problem, and in the Setup of this feature it is indeed hardcoded to lookup for Saga connection string, without checking if Sagas feature disabled or not.

Comment: @Evk - now back at work, I can confirm that disabling the storage session enables me to make further progress and still supports the scenarios I need timeouts for (e.g. delayed delivery). Care to write it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I have not much knowledge about NServiceBus, I just feel obliged to try to help people with high reputation when they ask questions :) So I don't have an explanation why it works like this, only where it fails. In stack trace you can see `NHibernateStorageSession.Setup`, and `NHibernateStorageSession` is one of the features. So it fails when trying to activate that feature. `Setup` starts like this:

```
protected override void Setup(FeatureConfigurationContext context)
{
  NHibernateConfiguration config = new NHibernateConfigurationBuilder(context.Settings, "Saga", new string[1]
  {
    "StorageConfiguration"
  }).Build();
  // the rest
}
```

Where second parameter is connection string suffix. In this case it is hardcoded to "Saga", and as you see - there is no check that `Sagas` feature is enabled or not. `NHibernateConfigurationBuilder` then tries to find a connection string for saga (or any more general connection string) and fails to do so with the exception message you observe.

So easy solution is to disable that feature via

```
endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<NHibernateStorageSessio‌​n>();
```

However you should take care of course and ensure functionality you need is not dependent on that feature. It's not entirely clear for me what this feature is for, and I didn't found any documentation for it (though of course its name tells us something about its purpose).

Comment: I have raised an incident with Particular to see whether they classify this (and another issue I found later) as actual bugs and whether they'll be resolved. It seems the *intention* of the configuration system is that you can apply fine-grained configuration and only "pay" for the features that you want to use but the practical reality seems somewhat different.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Dennis van der Stelt, a developer at Particular Software, makers of NServiceBus. I replied on your support case already, but wanted to update this question as well, so that others can find this as well. Evk mentioned most of it already, I just wanted to mention the GH issue and the complete code.

The following code configuration makes sure it doesn't complain about the saga connectionstring.

```
    endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<NHibernateStorageSession>();
    endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<MessageDrivenSubscriptions>();
    endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<Sagas>();
    endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<NHibernatePersistence, StorageType.Timeouts>();
```

Then just provide a connectionstring for timeouts

```
<add name="NServiceBus/Persistence/NHibernate/Timeout" connectionString="server=.\sqlexpress;database=nservicebus; Trusted_Connection=True;" />
```

That will make it work properly and as expected.

The reason why disabling the NHibernateStorageSession is necessary is because it is a feature inside the persister that is enabled. More information can be found in a GitHub issue I've created based on this case, [which can be found here](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.NHibernate/issues/286).

Answer (score 0):

> You can do it via (in order of precedence):

It just means the first point would take precedence over the other, if you need to set Saga, but otherwise just do one of the other points:

> - specifying 'NServiceBus/Persistence' connection string that applies to all persisters
> - specifying 'NServiceBus/Persistence/connection.connection_string' or 'NServiceBus/Persistence/connection.connection_string_name' value in AppSettings or your NHibernate configuration file.
>
> For most scenarios the 'NServiceBus/Persistence' connection string is the best option.

So you are not required to setup Saga, but it looks like you will not avoid setting a connection string somewhere.

Comment: But even if I set up Timeout storage, which is the only thing I want, I continue to get this error. It seems determined to set up Saga storage, no matter what I do. And as I say, I'm explicitly rejecting `NServiceBus/Persistence` since I cannot get the buy-in from higher-ups to consolidate databases at this time.

Comment: If you reject all the options this service propose for its setup, it looks like a dead end. I interpret the last point as writing you may tell to NHibernate where is its db directly in its own configuration file. Have you put your timeouts connection string there for testing? It looks to me this system checks many places but not the one specific to timeouts. So you have to choose one of the places where it checks for connection string.